# My samsumg s3 is acting like its on silent

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

My s3 wont make any tones to allert me to calls messages email or anything. Its as though its on do not disturb but isnt

Comment: Are there tones set in Settings-Sounds? Will there be any sound coming out if you go change one of them? It's supposed to play a preview of the sound at the current ringtone volume.

Answer (score 2):

The lack of sound may be caused by the malfunction of the battery, try removing it and repositioning it after checking that there is no swelling of it, if you still have problems trying to replace it.